# Find a probability integral

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, probability, multivariable-calculus

For $0 <t<1$  express the integral
$$
\int_0^\pi \int_{\max\left\{-1;\cos x - \frac{t}{\sin x}\right\}}^{\cos x}  \frac{dy}{\sqrt{1-y^2}} \, dx
$$
as a function of $t$ (without any  integrals).

I am sorry, but actually I don't know  any attempt  to do it.

Comment: What stops you from just doing the indefinite integral?

Comment: You have $\int\frac{dy}{\sqrt{1-y^2}} = \arcsin y + C$, so the inner integral is $\arcsin(\cos x)-\arcsin(\bullet)$, where $(\bullet)$ is a more complicated expression.  Then you have the identity $\arcsin(\cos x)) = \frac\pi2-x$.  The expression $\arcsin(-1)$ is easy to deal with; it's $\arcsin\left(\cos x-\frac{t}{\sin x}\right)$ where it seems to start getting complicated.

Comment: @Igor Rivin stops  the bad lower limit of integration

Comment: what is $\arcsin(\cos x-\frac{t}{\sin x})$?

Comment: Even if you *could* solve the indefinite integral, wouldn't you also need the two solutions $x_{1,2}(t)$ of $\cos x -\frac{t}{\sin x}=-1$ to calculate the result? That seems also hard to do.

Comment: I know that there is a nice presentation of the integral

Comment: I was able at least to solve $\cos x -t/(\sin x) = -1$, see my anwer.

Comment: Thank you! I will read your answer

Comment: Maybe one can solve the integral using a Taylor expansion $\int dx \arcsin(\cos x -\frac{t}{\sin x})=\int dx \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(x) t^n$. The integrals $\int dx a_n(x)$ should be of a solvable, trigonometric form. If you're lucky, the result can be reexpressed somehow nicely in $t$.

Answer (score 1):

This is no full answer, but too long for a comment, maybe somebody can use it.

Consider $f_t(x):=\cos x -\frac{t}{\sin x}$.

From a discussion of $f_t(x)$ we see, that for any $0<t<1$ it has a unique maximum greater $-1$ in $[0,\pi]$ and from there towards both interval boundaries $x\to 0,\pi$ it goes to $f_t(x)\to-\infty$ monotonously. Hence $\forall t$ there are two points $0<x_-(t)<x_+(t)<\pi$ with $f_t(x_\pm (t))=-1$ where the integration can be decomposed like

$$\int_0 ^\pi dx \int_{\min(-1,f_t(x))} ^{\cos x} dy (\cdot)=
  \left(\int_0 ^{x_-(t)}dx+\int_{x_+(t)}^\pi dx\right)\int_{-1} ^{\cos x}dy(\cdot) +  
\int_{x_-(t)} ^{x_+(t)}dx\int_{f_t(x)} ^{\cos x}dy(\cdot)$$

I will derive $x_\pm (t)$, the only missing piece of your puzzle is then to find $\int dx \arcsin(f_t(x))$, which I was not able to do.

We want to solve

$-1=f_t(x):=\cos x -\frac{t}{\sin x}$.

Multiply by $\sin x$, substitute $c=\cos x$, use $\sin x=\sqrt{1-c^2}$ and finally square it. You end up with

$$(1-c^2)(1+c)^2=t^2$$

Now comes the ugly work of solving this fourth order equation giving four solutions. Two of them are purely real, which read:

$$c_\pm(t)=\pm\frac{A(t)}{2}+\frac{B(t)}{2\sqrt{3}}-\frac{1}{2}$$ where

$$A(t)=\sqrt{\frac{A_1(t)-z(t)-4t^2}{3z(t)}+2}$$
$$A_1(t)=\frac{2\sqrt{3}}{B(t)}$$
$$B(t)=\sqrt{\frac{3z(t)^2+3z(t)+4t^2}{z(t)}}$$
$$z(t)=\left(2t^2+\frac{2t^2\sqrt{27-16t^2}}{3^{3/2}}\right)^{1/3}$$

The values of $x_\pm(t)$ are then given by

$$x_\pm (t)=\arccos(c_\pm(t))$$

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I'm not allowed to comment, haven't found a PM here either.
[This guy](http://teorver.pp.ua/english/eng.php) claims that he has found a beautiful answer to your problem after working on it for two months.

Scroll down [here](http://teorver.pp.ua/ukr/ukr.php?templ=sl) (you can also see the Google [translated](http://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=ru&tl=en&u=http%3A%2F%2Fteorver.pp.ua%2Fukr%2Fukr.php%3Ftempl%3Dsl) version).
If everything else fails you can try contacting him.

Comment: You should try to put at least part of that answer here.

Comment: That guy has posted that question as a challenge for his students, there is no solution available online. I've sent him link to this thread, maybe he would post a hint here.

Comment: Sorry, I assumed the solution would be in another page of the site.